# Xamarin.Forms Prism Master Detail Exception Queue Empty

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Using Xamarin.Forms and Prism I have a master detail page, a tabbed page and a content page.

I want to display the tabbed page first so I set it in App.xaml.cs

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MyMasterDetailPage/MyTabbedPage");
```

In my master page I have methods to navigate to the tabbed page and my content page

```
<Button Text="Home" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="MyTabbedPage" />
<Button Text="Other" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="NavigationPage/MyContentPage" />
```

This mostly works as intended, but when I use the master page to navigate to MyContentPage, then to navigate to MyTabbedPage it will fail saying "Queue empty".

I've looked at the https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Sandbox/Xamarin/HelloWorld sample which seems to be doing close to what I want but still can't get it working. If like that sample I replace the default NavigationPage with a custom one that sets ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation to true I still have the error, or false nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be fixed in Prism 7.2.0.708-pre prerelease as noted here https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1636